# WPF ComboBox binding automatically

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox

I'm making chatting program and I have an API for connect to chat server.

in API here is main class.

```
public partial class PengChat3ClientSock : IDisposable
```

well, I overrided `ToString` method too.

```
public override string ToString()
    {
        string s;

        if (ConnectedIP != null && ConnectedPort != null)
            s = ConnectedIP + ':' + ConnectedPort.Value.ToString();
        else
            return "";

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Nickname))
            return s;
        else
            return s + " \"" + Nickname + "\"";
    }
```

Well, in client program,

this is a list of sockets

```
private List<PengChat3ClientSock> socketList = new List<PengChat3ClientSock>();
```

And i have combobox which is to showing connection list

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="20">                   
</ComboBox>
```

Now, i want to bind ComboBox ItemsSource with variable `socketList`

I want to add/remove socket list when client create a new socket, and push back to the socketList or remove from the socketList.

It is possible?

Thanks.

Comment: ObsrevableCollection<PengChat3ClientSock>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ObservableCollection.

```
private ObservableCollection<PengChat3ClientSock> socketList = new ObservableCollection<PengChat3ClientSock>();
```

Then name combobox in XAML

```
<ComboBox Name="SocketListComboBox" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="20">                   
</ComboBox>
```

And in code (xaml.cs), in constructor just after InitializeComponents(); do

```
SocketListComboBox.ItemsSource = socketList;
```

Other way is to bind it in XAML;

```
<ComboBox Name="SocketListComboBox" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="20" ItemsSource = "{Binding socketList}">                   
</ComboBox>
```

In constructor set ComboBox DataContext to owner of socketList;
And socketList must be a property with public get.

```
public ObservableCollection<PengChat3ClientSock> socketList {get; protected set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an `ObservableCollection<PengChang3ClientSock>` instead of a plain list. The ObservableCollection will raise and CollectionChangedEvent when items are added or removed from the collection to notify bound controls.

Set the ObservableCollection as ItemsSource of the ComboBox like

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="20" ItemsSource="{Binding Sockets}">                   
</ComboBox>
```

This setup requires that the DataContext (ViewModel) of the ComboBox has a property Sockets encapsulating your ObservableCollection.

```
public ObservableCollection Sockets{
  get{
    return socketList;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
You should hold the list of sockets in an [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
private ObservableCollection]<PengChat3ClientSock> socketList = new List<PengChat3ClientSock>();
```

Then add a binding to the combobox like this:

```
ComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="20" ItemSource="{Binding socketList}>
```

The last thing you need to do is to set the DataContext of the Window with the ComboBox to the class which has the list.

```
DataContext = new ClassWithSocketList();
```

From now on every action you'll make on the list would have binding to the list.